# Поставить класс на каждый пятый элемент

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть такой HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

На каждый пятый пункт нужно поставить класс five.Вот код который не работает

```
  $("ul").children("li").each(function() {
    var indeItem = $(this).index("li");
    if(indeItem % 5) {
      $(this).addClass("five");
    }
  });
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: во-первых, колбэк у each() может получать параметры - элемент и индекс, поэтому не надо вызывать `index()`, а просто взять параметр. Во-вторых. если вызывает `index()` то делать надо это без параметров, не надо туда пихать `li`. В третьих условие `indeItem % 5` расставит вам классы на все элементы кроме пятых, это выражения проверяет остаток от деления, и он должен быть равен нулю, при этом еще надо участь сдвиг на 1, т.к. индексация с 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все гораздо проще:

```js
$('ul li:nth-child(5n+5)').addClass('five')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: гораздо проще вообще прописать это в css и не трогать js.

Comment: Тоже хотел это написать, но вдруг ему нужен для чего то новый идентификатор